# fopen() leading to a segmentation fault

Tags: c, fopen

I have the file name of a file stored in char *names. When I use `fopen(&names[0],"r")`, I am receiving a seg fault error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Missing terminating character '\0' in names?

Comment: Show us some code - we can't see it. so it'll be hard to find out what's going on.

Comment: Nonexistent file making `fopen()` return a null pointer...?

Comment: Yes, like @fvdalcin said.  Where is names defined and set?  Also, '&names[0]' is the same as simply 'names'.  Maybe show us more of your code.  And maybe boil it down into a very small test program.  Sometimes when I ask a carefully crafted question, I find the answer myself.

Comment: What about `fopen(names, "r")` according to the definition: `FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);` or if names is actually an array of strings, then `fopen(names[0], "r")`

Answer (score 2):

You already have a pointer to char as "names", so you could simplify that.
You can just pass that into fopen().

So as follows:

```
char * names = "/home/user/test.txt";
FILE * file = fopen(names, "r");
```

For the seg fault, we'd probably need to see what's in "names" or what it points to.

Comment: `char names[] = "/home/user/test.txt";`

Comment: It's pointing to strtok(buffer," ")

Comment: We need to see the buffer contents at this point, I think.  Can you post the whole thing?